# Retrieving data needed for ajax call for multiple lines

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I have a table with many rows. When you click on these rows they open up more detail about the row you click in. This could be based on an int or string.

I have wired jQuery up to anchor tags on each row which the user will click on. However previously when using Javascript inline you would pass something like this:

```
<a href="javascript: openNext('000001')"><img /></a>
```

Now when using events, I have lost the link to the '000001'.
Where should this value be placed for reference?

Comment: have to extend over the example with html code, for example, displaying the table with the tr where it expands, and to show tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<div id="somecontainer">
    <a href="#000001"><img /></a>
    ...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#somecontainer a').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        openNext(id);
        return false;    // to cancel native click event
    });
});
</script>
```

If you have lots of these on your page, say, over 100, you could also look into jQuery's `live` feature to increase performance.

Good luck

Comment: sounds good. I also went the route of adding custom attributes to the class. Gives it a bit more meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data as an ID for the `<tr>` of the row.  Then, in your click handler (assuming it's bound to the `<tr>`s), call `openNext(event.target.id)`